# server or domain defaulting back to index.html when index.php is entered

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Like others I want to be able to run both index.html and index.php on a site.  I want the default site.com to go to site.com/index.html and when typed into the address bar "site.com/index.php" I want this to go to "site.com/index.php" .  I have the same setup on another Wordpress site that works fine but I can't replicate it on a new one.

It will default to "site.com/index.html" stripping out the "index.html" in the address bar, but if I type site.com/index.php in the address bar it reverts to site.com .  It strips off the '/index.php' at the same time.  Here is my htaccess file.  Anything obvious? thanks~

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way WordPress works is that it tries to prevent duplicate URLs, thus, when you go to `example.com/index.php` it will (301) redirect you to `example.com/`.

I gues you could still have `index.php` and `index.html` by using the right order in your .htaccess (taking into consideration te redirect I mentioned):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Then you will have:

```
index.php ===> /
index.html ==> /index.html
```